# reference to type system.icloneable' claims it is defined in system.runtime but cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting this error on the 'new SqlConnection' line.

.netcore 2 web application
This is code is contained in a .netstandard class library that has the nuget packages:

system.runtime 4.3.1

System.configuration

I don't really know what the issue is here, this is my first .netcore application so there is probably something amateur i am missing here

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using EP.Data.Helper;
public class BaseDALayer
{
    private void ExecuteStoredProcedure()
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationHelper.GetConnectionString();
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void LogException(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I encounter the same problem, did you ever find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating MySql.Data nuget package to latest version (v8.0.23, in my case) resolved that issue